# Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable does not set any value

Tags: c#, c, mapserver, getenv

i'm encountering this issue with only

- Windows Server 2016 (Win2016) and
- VisualStudio-redistributable 2015 (VS-redist-2015 = msvcp14)

c# `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(key,val, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)` does not seem to set values that can be retrieved on the native-C app using [getenv()](https://github.com/szekerest/mapserver/blob/intramaps-ms7/fontcache.c#L162)

native-C app [getenv()](https://github.com/szekerest/mapserver/blob/intramaps-ms7/fontcache.c#L162) can read the values OK using Win2016 + VS-redist-2010

This works fine in Windows Server 2012 and 2008 using VS-redist-2015

Any thought / suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: in general, an environment variable is only visible in the creating process and in 'children' of the creating process

Answer (score 2):

By default `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(string <variable>, string <value>)` stores variables for the *current process*. To be more sure you need to use the overload that contains the target `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(string <variable>, string <value>, EnvironmentVariableTarget <target>)`. That way you can set the target to `Machine` or `User`.

Comment: we target EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process, which worked with everything but Win2016+VS-redist-2015)

trying now with EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine.

thanks for the tip

Comment: EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine did not work either.